# Command line option to get intermediate c code

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I want to see corresponding C code for a cpp file.
Is there any option in g++ compiler to get the intermediate C code on compiling the C++ classes??

Comment: There is no such a thing (no intermediate c code for c++).

Comment: I remember I have seen it somewhere. It was not exactly a C file but there were all global functions in it. No classes or member functions

Comment: What C++ compiler are you using?

Comment: @rici As tagged probably.

Comment: I tried with -fdump-tree-all option and the .gimple file was close to C code

Answer (score 3):

> *"I want to see corresponding C code for a cpp file."*

There's no such thing like a *corresponding C code for a `.cpp` file* (At least not with [g++](/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b) as tagged in your question). C and C++ are quite different languages, and it's hard (and not necessary) to transform all of modern C++ features to C code.

There was intermediate c code produced by very early implementations of the c++ compiler IIRC.

Nowadays c++ compilers produce either assembly code for the specified machine directly, or provide intermediate code using a backend. I can't find an option to see intermediary produced c code (probably since the compiler doesn't work this way).

The only options I'm aware of are `-S` to produce intermediary assembly code and `-E` that results in files after the CPP preprocessor was applied.

The [LLVM project seems to provide a backend](https://www.google.de/#q=llvm+c+backend), that translates anything from the AST parsed with the frontend (e.g. clang fo c++) to c language.

Well, I didn't try any of these linked search results myself.